# How to setup scrollview in a UIView to slide up a textfield that is hidden by keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiscrollview

I'm trying to setup a ScrollView to allow a text field to move above the keyboard as it's hidden when this text field get the focus.

The issue is: the view contains some labels, buttons and a text field for user inputs. All the tutorials I've read so far only showed how to write code but not how to layout things with UIScrollView. So, I've been trying to do it with my small knowledge of Objective C with no success.

What I've tried so far is:

put this text field as the UIScrollView subview with same size as the text field to notice it's not working as it should, so someone suggested me to also give the ScrollView the same size as the iphone (320x460) but when I do this my other buttons are not more responding as it seems the scrollview is above these objects....

Now, I really need your help just to know the proper way to fix the issue. The view layout looks like

```
I want to [BUY] [RENT] // UISegmentedControl

Min Rooms None (labels)

Min Price Any  (labels)

Max Price Any  (labels)

[enter postcode / area ] // this one is the text field

[Tab Bar ]
```

and the layout is so that the text field is hidden when keyboard shows up.

Thx in advance for your help,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440889/iphone-keyboard-hides-uiseachbar/7440996#7440996) which is quite similar to the problem youre having. You can either move up just the text field or the entire view, your choice.